# Regular expression for monitoring HTTP errors in apache logs

Tags: apache-2.2, regular-expressions

I'm looking for a regular expression that I can use to scan for HTTP errors in my standard apache log files.

I'm interesting in matching all lines that **don't** have an HTTP 200 or HTTP 204 return status.

I can match the lines that **do** contain either HTTP 204 or HTTP 200 return code

```
grep 'HTTP[^"]*" 204 \| HTTP[^"]*" 200'
```

But I would like to have the inverse. I'm also sure the expression above can be optimized.

I need to feed such regular expression to an external program, so using `grep -v` to inverse it is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary regular expressions don't include a way to negate anything except a single character, so I think you'll have to provide the whole list of codes you do want:

```
HTTP[^"]*" (1|20[12356]|3|4|5)
```

Perl-compatible REs do allow you to negate strings of text, so if you were using those you could use

```
HTTP[^"]*" (?!(200|204))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-v` switch gives you all the lines that don't match, so:

```
egrep -v 'HTTP[^"]*" (200|204)'
```

Comment: I want to do it in the regular expression itself. I need to feed a regex to a program that does the monitoring.

Comment: OK, then see my other answer.